# How get values from database one month old ignoring certain days from current date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, select

```
SELECT user.username, offer.* FROM offer 
INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = offer.userid 
 WHERE offer.date BETWEEN
 (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND NOW()
```

This work fine. It display record with in 40 days time interval, With current day/date as ref.

**Problem:**

I want to get records 40 or more days old  with last 40 days as ref.

i.e. it should ignore first 40 days from current date and display records older than that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can do this:

```
SELECT user.username, offer.* FROM offer 
INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = offer.userid 
WHERE offer.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)
```

You was pretty close to doing ;-)

Comment: @zeeshan don't forget check my answer as correct ;-)

Comment: @ andrian , its not allowing me to mark your answer as accepted :) ... I have used your code to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user.username, offer.* FROM offer 
INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = offer.userid 
WHERE offer.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Then it would be less than 40 days from now...

```
SELECT user.username, offer.* FROM offer 
INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = offer.userid 
WHERE offer.date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY)
```